# Notepad++ search/replace regular expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to search a line for a single digit followed by `</CourtZip>`  and replace it with the single digit followed by `</Phone>` using Notepad++.

I tried using `[0-9]</CourtZip>` and replace is `%1</Phone>`.

The result is to replace the single digit with the characters `%1` rather than the single digit so `6</CourtZip>` turns into `%1</Phone>`

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Use `$1` in the replacement part instead of `%1`

Comment: try https://regex101.com/

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE that still won't work without a capture group

Comment: @jonrsharpe: You're right, I was focused on `%1`

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You need to *capture* the single digit by surrounding it with parentheses: `([0-9])</CourtZip>`; and
2. You can use that captured group in the replacement using `\1` (i.e. the first capture group; you can also use `$1`, per JE SUIS CHARLIE's comment): `\1</Phone>`.

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly.  Do you recommend a good regular expression example page?  http://www.funduc.com/regexp.htm  did not do the job for me in this instance.

Comment: @Milton there are numerous regular expression tutorials out there - qiubix's suggestion of regex101 is good for developing and testing them with lots of helpful, colour-coded feedback.